# When is it appropriate to take the limit to evaluate the residue?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm very new to complex analysis and I'm primarily teaching myself. I mostly just stumbled across the concept of residues and such recently when trying to evaluate some annoying series that came up in PDEs, so I don't understand a lot about the subject.

With that said, I only just recently found that the residue can be very simply calculated by taking the limit as z approaches the pole i.e. $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint f(z) dz = \lim_{z\rightarrow a} (z-a)f(z)$$ and I have seen this work for problems like computing the residue for say $f(z) = \frac{z-\sin(z)}{z\sin(z)}$ for any pole $z=n\pi$ which was very useful because I was having quite a bit of trouble writing out the Laurent series. I went ahead and tested it for some other examples, but it failed for a couple examples I looked at being $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z^6}$ with pole z=0 since L'Hospital's Rule doesn't get applied enough times, and $f(z) = \frac{z}{\sin(z)}$ at pole $z=\pi$: $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{z}{\sin(z)}dz = \lim_{z\rightarrow \pi} \frac{z^2}{\sin(z)} = \frac{\pi^2}{0}$$, and the residue at this pole according to wolframalpha is $-\pi$.

So I can see that there are some limitations to this method, I just wanted to know what they were should I ever decide to use it in the future because maybe I've come across Taylor/Laurent series that is a bit more difficult to write out.

Also, is it possible to in some way modify these examples so that taking the limit *does* work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that $\lim_{z\to a } (z-a)f(z)$ is only equal to the residue of $f$ at $a$ in the case where $f$ has a pole of order one at $a$. This is why the formula does not work for the residue of  $\sin(z)/z^6$ at $0$, which is a pole of order $5$.

The second problem is, that you wrongfully compute the residue of $z / \sin(z)$ at $\pi$. The residue is given by the limit
$$
\lim_{z\to \pi} (z-\pi) \frac{z}{\sin{z}} =\lim_{z\to \pi} z \frac{(z-\pi)}{\sin{z}} = -\pi,
$$
which is not what you have written.

It is not hard to see why the above does not work for poles of higher order than 1 and what the correct formula in general is:

Let $f$ have a $m$-th order pole at $a$, meaning that the Laurent expansion of $f$ around $a$ has the following form
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=-m}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n,
$$
with  $c_{-m} \neq 0$.
Now $c_{-1}$ is the residue of $f$ at $a$ by definition.

If $m=1$, then
$$
\lim_{z \to a } (z-a) f(z) = \lim_{z \to a } (z-a)\sum_{n=-m}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n = \lim_{z \to a } \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n-1} (z-a)^n = c_{-1}.
$$
But if $m>1$ then it is clear from the above, that $\lim_{z \to a } (z-a) f(z) \neq c_{-1}$.

For a general $m$-th order pole we can do something similar:

Observe that
$$
(z-a)^m f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n-m} (z-a)^n,
$$
now the coefficient we want to extract is $c_{-1}$, where $n= m-1$ in the above power series. If we apply $\lim_{z \to a}$ to the above power series, then only the $n=0$ coefficient will survive, but that is not the coefficient we want. But we can make any coefficient be the $n=0$ term (modulo some constants) by differentiating a number of times first.

For example if $m=2$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dz} (z-a)^2 f(z) =\frac{d}{dz}   \sum_{n=0}^\infty  c_{n-2} (z-a)^{n} 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_{n-2} (z-a)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n-1} (z-a)^{n}
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{z\to a } \frac{d}{dz} (z-a)^2 f(z) = \lim_{z \to a } \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) c_{n-1} (z-a)^{n} = c_{-1} .
$$

The general formula for the residue of a $m$-th order pole can be derived in the same way. The result is
$$
c_{-1} = \lim_{z \to a } \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1} } (z-a)^m f(z).
$$

Comment: whoops I totally did screw up that example. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Also thank you for providing a formulaic representation of it using m! It helped a lot!